# Select all checkboxes at a time in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios

I have 8 checkbox `button`s (with title A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H) and one checkbox `button` (with title '`myButton`')

I want to select all 8 check boxes when I click on '`myButton`' checkbox, And if any one of the 8 is deselected, then uncheck '`myButton`' Check box.

let me know if anybody has answer.

Comment: How you have created the UIButton? by tag?

Comment: yes i created with tag.This button are on uiview

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14701326/select-all-checkboxes-at-a-time-in-iphone/14701607#14701607

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give your check box tags like: 1,2,3,...,8 and 9 for `myButton` Check box.

When you click on `myButton`:

```
if(//If my check box button is not already selected)
{
   //check all
   for (int loop = 1; loop<9;loop++)
   {
     UIButton *check = (UIButton *)[self.view viewWithTag:loop];
     //check that button
   }
}
else
{
   //uncheck all
}
```

For unchecking the `myButton` you can use:

```
UIButton *check = (UIButton *)[self.view viewWithTag:9];
//uncheck it
```

Edit:

If you created intermediate views for placing the button use that view instead of `self.view`.

```
 UIButton *check = (UIButton *)[placedView viewWithTag:loop];
```

Comment: i create in uiview ,so above code i edit on UIButton *check = (UIButton *)[self viewWithTag:loop];and set image on check ,then crash on [uiview setBackgroundImage:forState:]:

Comment: Thanks above code for select all is done successfully but now for uncheking 'mybutton' on single unchecking from 8 checkbox ,how do i have to call on function

Answer (score 0):

```
 //Creating a button

    for (int i = 100; i < 108; i++) {

        UIButton *checkBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        checkBtn.tag = i;
        checkBtn.frame = CGRectMake(15, 10+30*i-100, 250, 30);
        checkBtn.titleLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Btn %d",i];
        [checkBtn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"uncheck.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [customView addSubview:checkBtn];

    }
```

Select all button

```
-(void) selectAll:(id)sender
{
    for (int i = 100; i < 108; i++) {

        UIButton *selectBtn = (UIButton*)[customView viewWithTag:i];
        [selectBtn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"check.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    }
}
```